# Basic C++ Idioms / Techniques

Tags: c++, idioms

Note: marked as community wiki.

In recent days, I've realized how little I know about C++.

Besides:

- using the STL
- implementing RAII
- implementing ref-counted smart pointers
- writing my own policy-based template classes
- overloading operators << for fun

What other techniques are must-know for a good C++ programmer?

Thanks!

Comment: @anon Implementing RAII, certainly. Implementing ref-counted smart pointers? I hope the implementations that already exist are sufficient to prevent the need for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this should cover it:

[More C++ Idioms - Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms)

Comment: Yes, The C++ Idiom cover many some idioms that c++ engineer should know, such as PImpl, RAII, CRTP, copy and swap.

Answer (score 5):

- OO Design
- Types of exception safety guarantees (which is what most design patterns/idioms are based on).
- When to use which standard containers
- Boost

Comment: It seems C++ has been moving away from OO design in various respects in recent years...

Answer (score 2):

The first two are 'must know' for a good C++ programmer. 'Good C++ programmers' do not overload operators for fun.

Answer (score 2):

Basic:

- RTTI
- Virtual functions
- shared_ptr etc
- Templates
- Virtual inheriting
- Variadic macros

Also useful:

- Attributes (it depends on your compiler)
- Variadic templates
- Variadic functions
- Constexpr (sorting in compile time / calculating hash of strings etc... but the latter is related to the last section)
- Lambdas

Useful for brainfucking or in special cases:

- CRTP
- SFINAE
- inable_if (type traits)
- Foreach macro
- User-defined literals

Answer (score 0):

(hardly a must-know, but still useful) Writing domain-specific languages with operator overloading and template metaprogramming (see Boost.Spirit for a nice example) - but this is the kind of thing that makes shooting yourself in the foot easy, too.

Answer (score 0):

The way I used to improve my c++ is reading the source code of leveldb. Because leveldb is a product level code. So you can learn the cpp idiom and design pattern from a real product. Let me show you some example

Leveldb use the Pimpl idiom, almost in all of it's head file, such table.h table_build.h write_batch.h. You can learn from the code directly

Leveldb use many OO design pattern, such as build pattern, the table have the table_build class to build the table, the block have the block_build class to build the block

Leveldb also use the Iterator pattern, the iterator make us use leveldb more convenient.

So I think leveldb contain many idiom or design pattern that c++ engineer should know.