# What are your favorite C++ idioms?

Tags: c++, idioms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are your favorite C++ Coding Style idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276173/what-are-your-favorite-c-coding-style-idioms)

Dear C++ fans,

Could you list here your favorite C++ idioms? It is better to list those which are useful yet not well-known.

Firstly, I put one of mine:

To avoid tedious repeating `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {...}` , I use a macro like this:

```
#define LOOP(n) for (size_t _i = 0; _i < n; ++_i)
```

_i is a placeholder as bind uses.

So I can write:

```
vector<int> coll(100);
LOOP (100)
{
    coll[_i] = _i;
}

LOOP (100)
{
    auto a = _i;
    LOOP (100)
    {
        auto b = _i;
        cout << a << b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Re your exmaple: That's something your IDE should help you with, not obscure macros.

Comment: @Mchl, I think LOOP can more clearly express my intent here.

Comment: +1 for a decent question, but -1 for a terrible, terrible example. Net zero vote :)

Comment: @aix, I think macro is not always evil in C++ world.

Comment: Now who the hell has voted to close this one? Something's really wrong with guys out there. x-(

Comment: There are probably plenty of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759613/what-c-idioms-should-c-programmers-use, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096515/listing-elegant-c-idioms-closed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345177/basic-c-idioms-techniques. The OP's example is probably more of a *personal* idiom, not a universally accepted C++ idiom?

Comment: @UncleBens, Yes, that is my personal idiom. I think personal idioms which are not well-known may be more interesting.

Comment: What if you need two nested for loops? Using your macro, the placeholder vars would clash.

Comment: @mingos, LOOP (100) { auto a = _i; LOOP (100) { auto b = _i; cout << a << b; } }

Comment: @xmllmx, OK, but this syntax is cryptic. I prefer to write my loops explicitly: `for(int i=0;i<100;++i) for(int k=0;j<100;++j) { ... }` - other people will always know what it is.

Comment: @mingos, LOOP is not intended to be used everywhere. It is just useful for simple and count-fixed loops.

Comment: @xmllmx, maybe it's just me, but I find it confusing nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question but I think your example is a bad one!  Your `LOOP` macro does not make anything clearer - it actually hides your intent from programmers who don't use your macro, and it doesn't even look like C++ - my first reaction to your snippet would be "is that even C++?" or "what's wrong with an ordinary `for`?".  It may be tedious to write the loops over and over, but we all know everyone spends a lot more time reading and maintaining code than writing it in the first place, so it's hardly a waste of time writing out a full `for`, and it's much clearer.  You can continue to argue your point, but you should be aware that using macros in that way is **not** a widely accepted technique - other people looking at your code will call you out on it too.

Anyway, to add an actual answer - my favourite idiom in C++0x is a vector of unique_ptr:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> my_container;
```

It has the following advantages - essentially a safe vector of pointers:

- It provides random access in O(1) time
- Elements are guaranteed to never move in memory even when reallocating (so you can safely take the address of `T`s and store them)
- Fast for tasks like sorting (just shuffling some pointers, not copying heavyweight objects)
- Exception safe and helps prevent memory leaks - `erase()` on an element also releases the memory
- Flexible - you can `std::move()` pointers out of the container and put them somewhere else

It does have one or two disadvantages:

- Each element is allocated on the heap which may have performance implications if adding/removing a lot of elements, plus elements can be far apart in memory losing cache locality
- Iteration requires double indirection `(*i)->member` syntax - but I don't think it's a big deal

However, especially for heavyweight objects, I think it is nearly an ideal container.

Answer (score 9):

[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) is on the top of my list. There are so many cases when it just comes in handy...

Most useful as a generic implementation like Andrei Alexandrescu's [libloki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00667.html).

Comment: +1 RAII is the one C++ thing I really wish other languages supported.

Comment: +1 for RAII and answering-speed.

Answer (score 5):

## SFINAE

Comment: I knew you would say that. :D

Comment: @Nawaz : I wanted to say RAII but somebody already mentioned that. I had to name something *different*.

Comment: @Nawaz: Someone's been watching Judge Dredd too much :)

Answer (score 4):

RAII + opening a nested block if exact lifetime scope needed:

```
Lock lock(this);
ResourceHolder resource(findResource());
WorkerHolder worker(resource);
if (!worker)
    return false; // frees the resource and unlocks the lock
{
    WorkAssignment assignment(worker);
    assignment.Execute();
} // assignment cleaned up even in case of exception
...
```